# Stored Procedure to check the existence of email in tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL stored procedures. I need to write a SQL to check a email exists in multiple tables. If a email contains in First Table it returns true and should not execute the rest. Like wise if not I need to check the second table and if i found return true. Finally if i found in last Table I need to return true and else i need to return false.

I am stuck in achieving this. I tried like this. Gives me syntax errors. Please share me a solution for this.

```
USE Users_UserDetials;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Users.GetUserPermissions 
    @userEmail nvarchar(50),
    @areaId nvarchar(10),
    @villageCode nvarchar(10)
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users.GlobalUsers AS GU
    WHERE GU.UserEmail = @userEmail)

    ELSE

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users.AreaSpecificUsers AS AU
    WHERE AU.UserEmail = @userEmail)

    ELSE

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users.VillageSpecificUsers AS VU
    WHERE VU.UserEmail = @userEmail)

    ELSE

    '0'

GO
```

Comment: I lost the other answer which was perfect. I tested and it worked perfectly.Unfortunately it is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    USE Users_UserDetials;
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE Users.GetUserPermissions 
     @userEmail nvarchar(50),
     @areaId nvarchar(10),
     @villageCode nvarchar(10)
 AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users.GlobalUsers AS GU
WHERE GU.UserEmail = @userEmail)
BEGIN
 SELECT 1
END
ELSE

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users.AreaSpecificUsers AS AU
WHERE AU.UserEmail = @userEmail)
BEGIN
 SELECT 1
END
ELSE

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users.VillageSpecificUsers AS VU
WHERE VU.UserEmail = @userEmail)
BEGIN
 SELECT 1
END
ELSE

BEGIN
 SELECT 0
END

END
```

Comment: That's an ok answer, but you should also refer the user to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx. That way the user can further their education beyond rote repetition.

Comment: @JamieSee Please let me know given approach works, if not I can remove my post

Comment: It looks like it should work. I just meant to say that providing the additional info would help make the answer even more useful.